# Can I compile Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) to make a statically linked Apache httpd?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, phusion-passenger, mod-jk

I prefer to disable httpd dynamic module loading on my production server.

I've been using mod_jk linked statically into httpd for quite a long time and it proved to be stable.

Now I would like to add Ruby Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) to my httpd.

I wonder if it is possible to link it statically into Apache httpd the same way too? (without producing a huge httpd)

If it is, are there any potential pitfalls, safety or performance concerns having both mod_jk and mod_rails within the same executable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamic Shared Objects](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/dso.html) might solve your problem more readily. This not only would allow you to use a statically compiled mod_rails, but also any other compiled module you wish to load as you need.

Essentially once you statically compile the `mod_so` module, any other statically compiled modules can be added or removed via the LoadModule command in `httpd.conf`.

Frankly, I'd never recommend compiling several modules into one Apache compile.  I haven't noticed any performance pitfalls, but I've definitely noticed the great convenience of not having to recompile everything whenever I want to make a change. I especially appreciated this when testing module versions.

If by safety you mean security, treat security the same as when dealing with Apache and any module in a dynamic setting. You likely have done so already with mod_jk. I'd further think you'd have fewer potential threats since toy with precompiled source files, but honestly, I'm no expert on server security.

Comment: I don't understand how your DSO suggestion is different from the _dynamic setting_ that you are talking as an alternative. 

DSO loads modules dynamically, while I want to disable the dynamic loading whatsoever. I am explicitly **disabling** DSO in my httpd.

You're not recommending compiling modules into Apache b/c it's not convenient to make changes, but on production server I haven't made a single change to httpd in about 5 years. I've got development environment for changes.

Comment: I severely misread your question.  The only thing "static" about my suggestion is mod_so. I should stopped to think after typing "Dynamic."